# How to store bit values 0, 1, 2, 3 in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, bit

I have stored 0 and 1 in bit(1) column in mysql using true or false but now as per requirement I need to store 0, 1, 2, 3 in mysql bit(2) column using java. How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can work with BIT(2) column. First we will create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE rangeexample(
  val BIT(2) NOT NULL
);
```

Now we need to insert some data in it. I will insert the binary representations of 0,1,2 and 3:

```
INSERT INTO rangeexample(val)
VALUES(b'00'),(b'01'),(b'10'),(b'11');
```

It will also work if you directly insert integers (MySQL/MariaDB will cast them to bits automatically):

```
INSERT INTO rangeexample(val)
VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3);
```

The only issue is with reading the data. You store it as BIT(2) and therefore if you want to read them as integers, you must explicitly cast them to INT like this:

```
SELECT CAST(val AS INT) AS intval 
FROM rangeexample;
```

You can overcome this issue if you create "intval" as a virtual column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rangeexample(
  val BIT(2) NOT NULL,
  intval TINYINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(val AS INT)) VIRTUAL
);
```

That way you can just do:

```
SELECT intval
FROM rangeexample;
```

and that way you will not always have to write the CAST function in your SELECT queries. The virtual column is not wasting disk space (it is like a VIEW but built-in the table itself if I can say it like that as analogy).

An alternative solution is to use an integer datatype and TINYINT is the closest candidate for your values range. It can be done like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rangeexample(
  val TINYINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT val_range CHECK(val>=0 AND val<=3)
);
```

The CHECK will guarantee that the value is between 0 and 3. This solution will waste some disk space as TINYINT uses more bits that what you actually use; however usually this is more convenient so most people prefer it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the `cast` function worked for me. But there is a slight change it should be `SELECT CAST(val AS UNSIGNED INT) AS intval 
FROM rangeexample;`

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. Both INT and UNSIGNED INT will be able to display 0,1,2 and 3 :)